# Pass var between two Javascript/Jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am using Jquery to remove a default value in an HTML input on focus.

However, if nothing is entered into the input I want the default value to re-appear.

To try and do this I have created:

```
$( "#contact input" ).each(function( index ) {

        $(this).focus(function() {
          var valvalue = $(this).val();
          $(this).val(''); 
        });

        $(this).focusout(function() {
            var newvalvalue = $(this).val();
            if(newvalvalue == ''){
              $(this).val('', valvalue); 
            }
        });

    });
```

The `focus()` function works fine, but the variable `valvalue` does not get picked up by the `focusout` function.

Would anyone know a way to pass the `valvalue` variable to that 2nd `focusout` function?

Comment: Make `valvalue` global for both the event handlers

Comment: Surely not "global" ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `varvalue` visble by both event handlers. It can be done by declaring it outside their scope.

```
$( "#contact input" ).each(function( index ) {

   var valvalue; /* both event handlers can see it here */

   $(this).focus(function() {
       valvalue = $(this).val();
       $(this).val(''); 
   });

   $(this).focusout(function() {
       var newvalvalue = $(this).val();
       if(newvalvalue == ''){
           $(this).val('', valvalue); 
       }
   });    

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt that just mean the focusout function would just get a blank valvalue (ie not the value obtained in the first, focus function)?

Comment: No "focus out" without "focus" :)

Answer (score 1):

You're having an issue with closure scope in JS. Try defining varvalue outside your function so both functions reference the same variable.

```
$( "#contact input" ).each(function( index ) {
        var valvalue;
        $(this).focus(function() {
          valvalue = $(this).val();
          $(this).val(''); 
        });

        $(this).focusout(function() {
            var newvalvalue = $(this).val();
            if(newvalvalue == ''){
              $(this).val('', valvalue); 
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you can use `placeholder` property available in HTML5, if you don't want to support old browsers.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter here">
```